# Responding to a read receipt request using EWS

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, outlook-2010

I am writting something to auto process attachments parse them and do other types of things to them that are currently being done manually. My problem is when reading these emails they all require a response to a read receipt in outlook 2010. Most things I am seeing are ways to ask for a read receipt rather than respond to them. I saw that you can suppress them but I actually need to respond to them with a "yes this was read" essentially and cant seem to find a good way to do this.

```
if (tmpMsg.IsReadReceiptRequested){
//respond
}
```

I assume this is easy and I am just half checked out since its christmas time. Thanks

Comment: Look into `DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnSuccess`

Comment: I need the Microsoft Exchange equivalent probably thats System.Net.Mail option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to mark message as read. Exchange server will send automatically read receipt.
[An example how to mark message as read.](http://www.independentsoft.de/exchangewebservices/tutorial/findunreadmessages.html)